# Can not create simple databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I have created Emtpy Project in Android Studio. Next I have added `classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc2'` to build.gradle of my project and change layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
       <variable
          name="dataSource"
          type="com.example.demas.db1.DataSource" />
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.demas.db1.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Now I cannot build application and hav an error:

```
03-21 02:19:31.692 6822-6822/com.example.demas.db1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.demas.db1, PID: 6822
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demas.db1/com.example.demas.db1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class layout
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
```

Here is my DataSource class:

```
package com.example.demas.db1;

public class DataSource {
    private String name;

    public static DataSource get(String name) {
        return new DataSource(name);
    }

    public DataSource(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return String.format("Hello, %s!", name);
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use complete path from package name to till class name in the xml, <com.xyz.Data> </com.xyz.Data>, also you need to add schema at top to use custom tags.

Comment: I have full package name in the variable and relative layout (I have updated my question). Or do you mean something different ?

Comment: add this `<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.example.demas.db1.DataSource">`

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I have tried both of your advices, but it doesn't help

Comment: You can also check [this](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part2/) tutorial for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the error by removing `tools:context="com.example.demas.db1.MainActivity"` from `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Oh ho .I thought that on that time .By the by Happy to hear that you fix'es it .Move ahead .